# Using Linux to execute a query from Windows server by ODBC connection

Tags: linux, windows, openedge, progress-db

Here is the problem: We have a client that uses Progress Openedge database, we need to execute queries on this database from our servers.

Currently the drivers are installed on our Windows server, and the PHP code uses ODBC to run the queries.

Now we would like to move the code to a Linux server. We tried before to work with their linux drivers but that attempt has failed.

The question is, Is it possible somehow to run PHP code on a linux server, this code communicates with the Windows server, runs the query on the Windows server, and return the results to Linux?

How would you access to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for an ODBC client library for PHP that runs on Linux.

Comment: It's about buying and installing specific proprietary drivers of progress-db. We've tried this before, and didn't work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Your question boils down to "how can my Linux server ask my Windows server to do something" (where the "something" happens to be "talk to a database"), and there are a variety of ways to accomplish that.  You could run a web service (RESTful or SOAP) on the Windows server, for example.

Make sure you think about security:  if you deploy a service on your Windows server that lets remote clients modify a database, you have to be mindful of *which* remote clients are allowed to use that service.  The last thing you want to do is [accidentally allow random strangers to run arbitrary queries against your database](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Oklahoma-Leaks-Tens-of-Thousands-of-Social-Security-Numbers,-Other-Sensitive-Data.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid that I would have to go this route.
I was hoping that there is a way to get the query handler in Linux, and fetch the results one by one.
The thing is, that this way the Windows server has to understand my application, and fetch the exact fields I need for each query.

I'll mark this as accepted if there will no other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily; you could write a thin wrapper around the ODBC API that lets the Windows server receive queries it doesn't understand and send back results that it doesn't understand.  When you're building your own interface, you get to choose how high-level or low-level you want to be.

Comment: That's correct. I currently fetch fields individually per row by using odbc_fetch_row and odbc_result, since in some rows I don't need all fields. In any case, I guess the different in performance terms are negligible. Thanks. I'll consider this approach.

Answer (score 0):

We have a [Knowledgebase Article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000027930) detailing some setup procedures for Linux installations; it also has a video explaining some aspects of the setup. If the other answered haven't provided a complete solution for you, hopefully our article can at least get you started in the right direction.

Also keep in mind that depending on your version of OE, the driver libraries may be different.